Looking to combine LoRa with Gaussian Frequency-Shift Keying Mode
I'm looking to increase the throughput of my LoRa signal by using GFSK. I'm new to LoRa and have no experience managing radio signals. I'm a programmer though and would like to develop firmware for my LoRa devices. Is there any good starting points as suggestions?

your question is a better fit at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions

Reposted and referenced. Thanks for notifying me.

What region are you in? GFSK is already used by LoRaWAN in some regions. Also what are your devices? Are you using LoRaWAN or raw LoRa? If LoRaWAN, on your own network or a public one? If the latter, which network?
